# How to calculate Math.PI/180 once and store in a variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I calculate Math.PI/180 in my code and store the number that is calculated in a variable so the game loop does not recalculate multiple times? I am really new at actionscript, and i'm having a hard time with game loops and the calculation process, so if you could please show me the code in doing so?

```
function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;


    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not going to change this value at run-time, your best bet is to make it a constant value:

`public static const PI_OVER_180: number = Math.PI / 180;`

If you're calculating this value inside your function, you'll be recalculating it every time the function is called, and float math is expensive. If you know you're going to need a number often and it won't change, make it a constant.

Comment: Great point! It is important to note that this will only work if he has implemented classes for his code though. If he hasn't, this variable can still be moved outside of the function to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

In this I have simply stored the calculation of Math.PI/180 into a variable as you asked and reused it in other parts of the code.

```
function moveEnemies():void
{
    var tempEnemy:MovieClip;
    var halfPI:Number = Math.PI / 180;

    for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        tempEnemy = enemies[i];
        if (tempEnemy.dead)
        {
            score++;
            score++;
            roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
            enemies.splice(i,1);

        }
        else
        {

            tempEnemy.rotation += (Math.round(Math.random()*.4));
            tempEnemy.y +=  (Math.cos(halfPI*tempEnemy.rotation))*tempEnemy.speed;
            if (tempEnemy.x < 10)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = 14;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.x > stage.stageWidth - offset)
            {
                tempEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth - offset;
            }
            if (tempEnemy.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                removeEnemy(i);

                lives--;
                roachLevel.lives_txt.text = String(lives);
            }
        }
    }
}
```